# elasticsearch boost by popularity when field could be missing

Tags: elasticsearch

In the documentation http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/boosting-by-popularity.html#CO112-4 it is explained how to boost docs according to a numeric field. But the `field_value_factor` doesn't work if a field is absent for any of the documents. What's the best way around that when a field is necessarily absent sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is e.g.

```
{
   "query":{
      "function_score":{
         "functions":[
            {
               "filter":{
                  "exists":{
                     "field":"views"
                  }
               },
               "field_value_factor":{
                  "field":"views",
                  "factor":1.2,
                  "modifier":"log1p"
               }
            },
            {
               "FUNCTION":{}
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

i.e. apply an array of function-filter pairs. The first function checks the field is present (`views` in my case) and the second has a missing filter (equivalent to `match_all`) and an empty function - i.e. the score is unmodified.

Comment: A better solution should be to put `missing: 1` in there so you don't lose the documents

Comment: where would that go exactly?

Comment: under `field_value_factor`

Comment: @f13ts Thanks you, didn't know this "exists" filter, it works well.